# Can you output a button via controller in Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-8

I have a live search via my controller method and it outputs the results but I want to have a button for editing present too

what I have tried:

```php
function action(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $output = '';
        $query = $request->get('query');
        if ($query != '') {
            $data = DB::table('customers')
            ->where('id', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
            ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
            ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->get();

        } else {
            $data = DB::table('customers')
            ->orderBy('is', 'desc')
            ->get();
        }

        $total_row = $data->count();
        if ($total_row > 0) {
            foreach ($data as $row) {
                $output .= '
                    <tr>
                        <td>' . $row->id . '</td>
                        <td>' . $row->email . '</td>
                        <td><a href="{{url("cust-edit/".$data->id)}}" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a></td>
                    </tr>
                ';
            }
        } else {
            $output = '
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" colspan="5">No Data Found</td>
                </tr>
            ';
        }

        $data = array(
            'table_data' => $output,
            'total_data' => $total_row
        );

        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

Edit: Added the full method.
Note. this live search should not refresh the page, rather replace values

Comment: Can I ask why you are not returning a blade view and rendering this in a blade view. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade

Comment: I did have static values displaying in the blade view, being my first time working with ajax, I'm not too sure how I could have put this in the blade file

Comment: pass $data variable in view("view path",compact("data")); it will call the view then put all the content you had display by "echo".

Comment: @MunawarHussian how would you go about doing that. sorry, I am just starting out

Comment: share the complete method here please edit the above code

Comment: _this gives a link, not a button_ so you are getting a edit link but  bootstrap `btn` class is not working??

Comment: This looks like the perfect use case for [`forelse`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#loops) in Blade templates

Comment: that does sound confusing... Originally I had a page that displayed this data and gave the option of editing via the button but now that my search is a live one, it messes things up

Comment: <td><a href="{{url("cust-edit/".$data->id)}}" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a></td> change the $data->id to $row->id then try it

Comment: @MunawarHussian that doesn't work, it redirects to burl

Comment: can you share the live link if you have and the id and email show correctly?

Comment: hmmm at the moment it is local

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend you do a lot of refactoring and read some more of the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x).

I've done some refactoring, I haven't tested, and there is a lot more work you'll need to do (I can't do it for you, I don't have enough information).

---

We'll start with the controller.

```php
public function action(Request $request)
{
    if (!$request->ajax()) {
        return;
    }

    $customers = DB::table('customers')
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc');
    
    if ($request->has('query')) {
        $query = '%' . $request->get('query') . '%';
        $customer = $customer->where('id', 'LIKE', $query)
        ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', $query)
        ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', $query);
    }

    $customers = $customers->get();

    return view('path.to.view', compact(
        'customers'
    ));
}
```

Let's walk through the changes.

1. I utilised the "early returns" code practice. This means that we don't wrap the entire method in an if statement, but rather exit out early out of the method.
   It is far easier to read this way.
2. Renamed `$data` to `$customers`. This is a simple change but makes your code easier to read. (Can you see the theme here)?
3. Moved the duplication of the query builder out of the if statement. It's a "builder", so we can build part of the query that is the same. This code practice is called "DRY" or Don't Repeat Yourself.
4. Then we check if the `$request` has a specific key. This is just keeping our code very Laravel-centric.
5. Now we add to the `$customers` query builder with the query from `$request`.
6. Don't forget to call `get()` to 'get' all the records from the database. If the request didn't contain query, this part will still be run as normal.
7. Return a Laravel view, and pass in our `$customers` Collection. In Laravel, paths are separated by dots / `.` / full stops / periods.

At this point, you'll need to change how your AJAX query works and returns data.
I can't do this for you. Please attempt to do it yourself, and if you can't then open a new question.

---

Okay, so it's time to create our view (rather than returns that abhorrent string)!

```php
<table>
    @forelse ($customers as $customer)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $customer->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $customer->email }}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ url("cust-edit/".$customer->id) }}" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @empty
        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="5">No Data Found</td>
        </tr>
    @endforelse
</table>
```

Laravel Blade templates provide a very useful directive called [`forelse`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#loops) which lets you iterate over an iterable, and if the iterable contains no elements, then it runs a separate section of code.

As you can see, this is a much better approach than counting records and doing this yourself.

One final thing, I highly recommend using [named routes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#named-routes) and replacing:

```
url("cust-edit/".$customer->id)
```

with

```
route("customer.edit", ["customer" => $customer])
// or
route("customer.edit", compact('customer'))
```

I'll give you a hint for the route.
It won't include [type hinting](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-binding) of [models](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#generating-model-classes), because it doesn't look like you use models.

```php
Route::name('customer')->prefix('customer.')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/cust-edit/{customer}', function ($customer) {
        $customer = DB::table('customer')->where('id', $customer)->first();
        // code...
    })->name('edit');
});
```

Comment: `if ($request->has('query')) {
        $customer = $customer->where('id', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->get('query') . '%')
        ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->get('query') . '%')
        ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->get('query') . '%')
    }`  does this not need a semicolon?

Comment: @jamesdayley1996 I missed it out; that’s the issue with typing into here - no linting! But is that really the only takeaway from my answer that you have…?

Answer (score -1):

In Laravel, it's not recommended to generate HTML directly within a controller method. Instead, you should separate your HTML presentation logic from your controller logic by using views. In your case, you can create a Blade view that contains the HTML for your table rows and buttons, and then pass the data to this view from your controller.

Here's how you can refactor your code to use a view:

1. Create a Blade view file. Let's call it `customerTable.blade.php` in the `resources/views` directory. This view will contain the HTML structure for your table rows:

```php
<!-- resources/views/customerTable.blade.php -->
@foreach($data as $row)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $row->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->email }}</td>
        <td><a href="{{ url("cust-edit/".$row->id) }}" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

2. Modify your controller method to load this view and pass the data to it:

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

public function action(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $output = '';
        $query = $request->get('query');
        
        if ($query != '') {
            $data = DB::table('customers')
                ->where('id', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
                ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
                ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
                ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                ->get();
        } else {
            $data = DB::table('customers')
                ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                ->get();
        }

        $total_row = $data->count();

        if ($total_row > 0) {
            // Load the Blade view and pass the data
            $table_data = View::make('customerTable', ['data' => $data])->render();
        } else {
            $table_data = '<tr><td align="center" colspan="5">No Data Found</td></tr>';
        }

        $response = [
            'table_data' => $table_data,
            'total_data' => $total_row,
        ];

        return response()->json($response);
    }
}
```

In this refactored code, we load the Blade view using `View::make()` and pass the `$data` array to it. Then, we render the view and store the generated HTML in the `$table_data` variable, which is included in the JSON response.

By following this approach, you keep your controller logic clean and separate the HTML presentation logic into a Blade view, which is a recommended practice in Laravel.